# Apache Spark: count vs head(1).isEmpty

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

For a given spark df, I want to know if a certain column has null value or not. The code I had was -

```
if (df.filter(col(colName).isNull).count() > 0) {//throw exception}
```

This was taking long and was being called 2 times for 1 df since I was checking for 2 columns. Each time it was called, I saw a job for count, so 2 jobs for 1 df.

I then changed the code to look like this -

```
if (!df.filter(col(colName).isNull).head(1).isEmpty) {//throw exception}
```

With this change, I now see 4 head jobs compared to the 2 count jobs before, increasing the overall time.

Can you experts please help me understand why the number of jobs doubled? The head function should be called only 2 times.

Thanks for your help!
N

Update: added screenshot showing the jobs for both cases. The left side shows the one with count and right side is the head. That's the only line that is different between the 2 runs.

[image]

Comment: is the dataframe created for a parquet file?

Comment: A "job" is a transformation from a stable source to a stable destination. 7 head jobs seems to mean 7 partitions on data. It is trying to execute the action. On the other hand count is just reading stats on the file.

Comment: the dataframe source is a file and is eventually saved to parquet. so does this mean the count reads the source file stats and is the better way to go as far as performance is concerned? There isn't any explicit paritionby used on the dataframe.

Comment: If the source file is a parquet then it has statistics and count is pretty fast. If source file is not a parquet then head is far better. Count on large file will take longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataframe.head(1)` does 2 things -
1. Executes the action behind the dataframe on executor(s). 
2. Collects 1st row of the result from executor(s) to the driver.

`dataframe.count()` does 2 things -
1. Executes the action behind the dataframe on executor(s). If there are no transformation on the file and parquet format is used then it is basically scanning the statistics of the file(s).
2. Collects count from executor(s) to the driver.

Based on the source of dataframe being a file which stores statistics and absence of any transformation, count() can run faster than head.

I am not 100% sure why there are 2 jobs vs 4. Can you please paste the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the screenshot above. Not all head jobs are slower than the head ones, but 4 jobs vs 2 makes the total time more.

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to say just looking for this line of code, but there is one reason for head can taking more time. `head` is a deterministic request if you have `sort` or `order_by` in any part that will request a shuffle to always return the first row. With the case of `count` you don't need the result ordered, so there is no need to shuffle, basic a simple mapreduce step. That is probably why your `head` can taking more time.

Comment: thanks for your response. There is no ordering/sorting going on here. All I want to check is if there are any rows with missing values for certain columns (2 columns in this case).